# Is it possible to PostMessage to a Win32 HWND from JavaScript (running in the IE browser ActiveX control)?

Tags: javascript, c++, internet-explorer, com, activex

I have a native C++/Win32/MFC app with a dialog that contains the IE ActiveX browser control.  The control renders a generated HTML page which contains some JavaScript.

This is yet another followon to a series of questions I posted in which my end goal is trying to communicate from the Javascript in the HTML back to the main dialog which contains it.

My original approach was to go about creating a COM object which the Javascript could talk to.  I received some help and advice on doing this.  However, in thinking about this more, since the end goal is just communicating with the dialog, I'm thinking maybe thats not necessary.

Since the Javascript can create and invoke on ActiveX objects, maybe there's an existing one I can use?

Is there a way, using an ActiveX object to, from the Javascript, do a Win32 PostMessage to a given HWND?  i.e. an existing object to avoid having to create one myself?  Some sort of system object provided that I could create from within the Javascript?

Or maybe some other way in Javascript to post a message to the Win32 HWND?

If so, I think I wouldn't need to create any COM object myself, I could just respond to events by posting messages to the containing dialog (the dialog is generating the HTML and so could provide the HWND then).

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I am very interested

Comment: No I have not.  It would be really nice to be able to have a dialog showing an HTML file where button clicks in the HTML could easily be sent back to the app.  So far it seems you'd have to write a COM server and go through a bunch of hoops (seems way overcomplicated) or perhaps figure out a way to post a simple message which is why I posted this.  If you figure it out I've love to hear about it.